Pullback connection definition
I see in a text the following theorem: If $f:N\to M$ a smooth map between smooth manifold, and $\nabla$ is a connection over tangent bundle $TM$, then there is a unique und natural extension
$$
\bar\nabla: \Gamma(TN)\times \Gamma(f^*(TM))\to \Gamma(f^*(TM)), \ (A,Y)\mapsto \bar\nabla_AY
$$
such that: (i)$\bar\nabla$ is a connection over pullback bundle $f^*(TM)$; (ii)$\forall X\in\Gamma(TM)$, it holds that $\bar\nabla_A(X\circ  f)=(\nabla_{f_*A}X)\circ f$; (iii) $\forall A,B\in\Gamma(TN)$:
$$
T(f_*A,f_*B)=\bar\nabla_Af_*B-\bar\nabla_Bf_*A-f_*[A,B]
$$
and (iv):
$$
R(f_*A,f_*B)=\bar\nabla_A\bar\nabla_BY-\bar\nabla_B\bar\nabla_AY-\bar\nabla_{[A,B]}Y
$$
where $T$ and $R$ are the torsion and curvature.
My confusions are:

In what sense the author says that it's an "extension"? My thought is that it should be a restrict, since $\Gamma(f^*(TM))$ can be viewed as a "subset" of $\Gamma(TM)$.
How is e.g. $\nabla_{f_*A}X$ in (ii) defined? I know that connection is local, so we can write $\nabla_vX$ (where $v\in T_pM$) for $\nabla_YX$ with arbitrary $Y\in\Gamma(TM)$ with $Y_p=v$. Is the case $\nabla_{f_*A}X$ similar? $f_*A$ is not a well defined vector field on $M$, because some points in $M$ have no preimage and $f_*A$ has no definition over these points, so is it meant that it is $\nabla_YX$, where arbitrary $Y\in\Gamma(TM)$ such that $Y_{f(p)}=(f_*A)_{f(p)} \ \forall p\in N$? If yes, how can the existence of such $Y$ be guaranteed?


What is the text you are reading?

@Deane It is a lecture notes of our professor in a course about differential geometry and is written in German, and I can't reach him by Email, so I ask here.

First, note that if $\nabla$ is a connection on a vector bundle $E$ over $M$, then for each section $s$ of $E$ and $p \in M$, it defines a linear map \begin{align*} T_pM &\rightarrow E_p\\ V &\mapsto \nabla_Vs(p). \end{align*}
Given a smooth map $f: N \rightarrow M$, you can define the pullback bundle $f^*E$ and pullback connection $f^*\nabla$ as follows.
First, as you know, the fiber of $f^*E$ over $q \in N$ is $E_{f(q)}$. But you also need to define what a smooth section of $f^*E$ is (or, equivalently, define what the local trivializations are). I like to do it as follows:
Let $(e_1, \dots, e_k)$ be a frame of smooth sections of $E$ over $M$. Then the bundle structure of $f^*E$ is defined to be one such that $$ (e_1\circ f, \dots, e_k\circ f) $$ is a frame of smooth sections of $f^*E$. Therefore, a map $s: N \rightarrow f^*E$ is a smooth section if and only if there exist smooth functions $a^1, \dots, a^k$ on $N$ such that $$s = a^1e_1\circ f + \cdots + a^ke_1\circ f. $$
You can now define the pullback connection as follows, using the fact that it is a derivation:
\begin{align*}
f^*\nabla s: T_qN &\rightarrow E_{f(q)}\\
V &\mapsto \langle da^k(q),V\rangle e_k(f(q)) + a^k(q)(\nabla_{f_*V}e_k)(f(q)) \end{align*}
This and some other stuff is discussed in a blog post.

But should the first argument of $f^\nabla s$ be a section over $TN$, i.e. a vector field over $N$? How could you do this for just a single tangent vector? Do you mean that for each $q\in N$, $((f^\nabla)_As)q:=(f^*\nabla){A_q}s$ where $A\in\Gamma(TN)$ and $A_q\in T_qN$? Also could you explain my question 2?

The value of  $(\nabla_Vs)(p)$ depends only on $V(p) \in T_pM$. If you want only the value of the covariant derivative of $s$ in a direction $V$ at $p \in M$, you only need $V \in T_pM$. The value of $V$ at points other than $p$ are not needed. My answer was directed towards question 2. As for question 1, I agree that "extension" does not seem appropriate.

@Deane I wouldn’t mind using “extension” here because in practice one uses the same symbol $\nabla$ for both the original and the pullback (because the two are so obviously related). With this understanding, the two slots $\nabla$ can take have been “extended” because it can eat not just sections of $E$ and tangent vectors to $M$, but for any smooth map $f:N\to M$ it now eats any smooth lift of $f$ to $E$, and any vector tangent to $N$. So morally it’s like an “extension of the idea”, rather than being a larger or smaller ‘subset’ (such a direct comparison wouldn’t even make sense of course).

If $\omega_e$ is the connection matrix of $\nabla$ w.r.t. some local frame $e$ on some open $U \subseteq M$ (i.e. $\nabla e = e\omega_e$) then $f^*\omega_e$ defines a connection matrix w.r.t. $f^*e$ of a unique connection $\bar\nabla$ on $TN$.
For 1. : it is maybe better called induced connection.
For 2. : you are right. For every tangent vector $v \in T_p Q$ on a smooth manifold $Q$ there is always a vector field $Y \in \Gamma(TQ)$ with $Y_p = v$. It can be seen local in a chart easily and then extend it with a bump function.

Could you explain for 2 about $\nabla_{f_*A}X$? Here the first argument is not a tagent vector, also not a vector field on $M$, so I don't know how is it defined.

Maybe better phrased in (ii): for all $f$-related vector fields $A \in \Gamma(TN)$ and $B\in \Gamma(TM)$ it holds $\bar \nabla_A (f^* X) = (\nabla_B X)\circ f = f^*(\nabla_B X)$.
